# using .call vs. passing "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, optimization

I know that if you have some javascript function and you want to call it such that using `this` within it would refer not to the object on which it was directly called you can use `func.call(thatObject,param,and,more,params...)`.

But suppose you are the writer of `func` and the only usage for func is via func.call,
Why would you not define it to begin with as:

```
function func(that,param,and,more,params...) {
   //and in here use *that* and not *this*
}
```

yep, it looks less "cool" because its not a method of an object,
but hey if the only usage for func is via func.call it all seems like just extra code and overhead.

Am I missing something here? or is the source code in which I have seen this pattern just "over OOed" ?

Comment: Why is this tagged "performance"? And where is the "optimization" sub-question?

Comment: @Tomalak, because there is probably a performance difference, one is calling an extra function to get the proper scope, while the other is sending around a variable with a pointer to the object. Actually, you have 130k plus rep, why am I arguing with you...

Comment: @RustyToms: That would be premature optimization, then. The only valid question with the performance tag is one that contains a profiler report.

Comment: it was tagged with those two tags because IMHO the choice of using the .call is bad for performance (especially in the context of the code where is saw it that runs many times per second) and I thus changing this pattern to a simple function call would increase performance.

Comment: There is no performance difference between calling a function directly and calling it via `.call()` or `.apply()`. Why do you think that? Have you measured? Does it matter? Are you sure you are actually interested in the performance implications or are you really asking why `.call()`/`.apply()` exist in the first place?

Comment: there are some functions that can be used in both form, normal invoke and invoke using `call()` for example `Array.prototype.slice`

Comment: @ABFORCE: **All** JavaScript functions can be invoked using `call` and `apply`. It is one of the fundamental language features.

Comment: @elusive I knew it, but my mean is the usage of `call` and `apply` is to provide another context for the function not the normal context. for example `Array.prototype.slice` is intended to slice the calling array object but this can be use to slice another array like object

Comment: What is that site where you can put in code and it runs it a million times, and everyone who visits it runs the code, and it keeps track of performance on each browser? I cannot remember. @epeleg, you should make a comparison test there.

Comment: @RustyToms: [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: @elusive I don't see anything in the description for the optimization tag that says that I "The only valid question with the performance tag is one that contains a profiler report"...

Comment: jsperf.com is a good idea and I might try it later. But my Q was if the code is just "over OOed" (or there is a good reason to code this way?)

Comment: @epeleg: Well, the tag wiki _does_ contain a paragraph about premature optimization. Profiling prevents premature optimzation pretty effectively, which is why I suggested using it.

Comment: Ok, smarty pantses, (@Tomalak), there is a big difference.  http://jsperf.com/callvsthisasargument  I reserve the right to have made a newb mistake somewhere.

Comment: @elusive: Its not that I am against profiling nor that I am not aware of premature optimization. Its just that for some reason Tomalak said that it was not optimization related... and someone even downgraded me for for some reason....

Comment: @RustyToms, Thanks for the test suit. Even I did not expect such a difference... :)

Comment: @RustyToms Well, I stand corrected. I find the dimension of the difference rather suspicious, though...

Comment: @Tomalak, run it yourself.  It is basically equivalent to calling the function inside of the object, within its natural scope, as ZenMaster has [shown here](http://jsperf.com/call-vs-apply-vs-bind-kbrain/5).

Comment: @RustyToms See http://jsperf.com/call-vs-this-argument-2 - I'm "only" seeing a 20-25% difference.

Comment: @RustyToms Hm. What expensive operation does my test add? (Related: What good is a function that can run several millions of times a second doing *exactly nothing*? What does that prove? Is it a useful vehicle to draw conclusions from?)

Comment: @Tomalak, I deleted that comment, I thought you were linking to a revision someone made on my test, sorry, my bad. It is actually very interesting that there is such a large difference between your test and my test and ZenMasters test. I am trying to figure it out. If you see something I did wrong, let me know, I have never used jsperf before. But you need to explain like you would to a small child :)  However, I think a function that does as close to nothing as possible is most useful, since we are not testing how fast the function runs, we are testing how fast the function is called.

Comment: I think the raw test here is interesting, but it does not actually answer the question as to whether the performance increase would be significant at all when used in the application described by OP. That is what the profiler should be used on.

Comment: @RustyToms Yes, you'd be able to flesh out more distinctly the difference between several ways to call a function. However if the *call* part of the function makes up such a small part of the actual *run* part that adding a single actual operation to the function body makes such a difference... then discussing the differences in the call part is a rather futile exercise (unless you're writing a library, have identified the hot spots and start to go crazy on some inner loops to gain a few percents).

Comment: well, the code is actually from a library. and runs as part of an animation loop. And again not every time that you chose to write in a way that is a bit faster you are pre-optimizing... if there is no good reason to USE .call - then why not use direct calls even if the benefist is "only" 20-25%? again, note that my original Q just asks if there is a good reason to prefer the `.call` over the direct call... if there is none then even a performance benefit of 5% would be a good enough reason for me to prefer the direct call... [again - in my scenario] I am not advocating the removal of `.call`.

Comment: b.t.w. I am not even saying that if you already have a library with such a pattern you must "fix" it... but next time you write one... it would probably be better to use a direct call instead of .call() when there is no good reason to use it...

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a large performance difference.  Using

```
func(){
  //code here, this.something
}
func.call(thatObject)
```

according to the first couple of tests is about 8 times slower than using

```
func(that){
  //code here, that.something
}
func(thatObject)
```

Test it yourself, [JSPerf here](http://jsperf.com/callvsthisasargument)

Ultimately though, speed alone is rarely the most important factor in which code we use. Code is designed for people as much as it is for computers, we need to communicate our intentions clearly to both. Whichever makes the code cleanest is best, and we should follow conventions whenever it is feasible. I personally prefer the second option here, but I think the general convention is the first. So I think you use `call` in most situations, except for when you need the fastest code possible or if the convention changes.

Comment: There is one in existence already: http://jsperf.com/call-vs-apply-vs-bind-kbrain

Comment: @ZenMaster, none of those tests include the func(thatObject) test.

Comment: They do now in the latest revision.

Comment: Also, before you act all mighty - http://webreflection.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/arguments-callee-call-and-apply.html

Comment: in that webreflection blog they say "This means that even where it is possible to avoid it, we feel cooler using such mechanism" ... oddly enough they also say "CROME: .... otherwise call is 4X faster than apply and, apparently, even faster than a direct call" (which does not seem to be the case now).

Comment: and finally they say `"A direct call is faster, cross browser speaking, and specially for those shared functions without arguments, we could avoid usage of call or apply, a self reference as argument is more than enough.
arguments object should be forbidden, if we talk about extreme performances optimizations. This is the only real constant in the whole bench, as soon as it is present, it 
slows down every single function call and most of the time 
consistently."`

Comment: @ZenMaster, I just ran [your test](http://jsperf.com/call-vs-apply-vs-bind-kbrain/5) in Firefox 25, and that result is very strange! The direct(local) test is the fastest for all the other browsers, but one of the slowest on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

`func.call` is intended to be used when an alternative (or any) context for the function is needed to be provided.

Your suggestion is odd, since, when you define the function using this pattern:**

```
function func(that,param,and,more,params...) {
   //and in here use *that* and not *this*
}
```

it's either:

**doesn't belong to any object**

in which case passing an object to act as `this` doesn't make any sense, since there should be no `this.someThing` calls to begin with

or **belongs to a different object or is defined to be a plug to an object**

in which case it does **exactly** what `func.call` would do, while contaminating the definition of the function with redundant parameter.

UPDATE:

Think of the second example in this way - imagine that some set of Objects (what you'd call from the same "class") allow injection of arbitraty functions, say for iteration over all properties of the object and some summary or manipulation or what have you.

In Java, the common pattern is to create an Iterator and pass it, and **its main purpose is to serve as sort of placeholder** so that `next` and `hasNext` methods can be called - since Java doesn't really have object-less functions. (granted there is some additional logic there, but let's leave it alone for the sake of this discussion).

JavaScript does not neeed this! All these `call` and `apply` methods do not **need** to have some additional Iterator object to hold them. They can be defined "detached" from any object, while still with intention to be used in a context of one (hence `this` usage in their code) and injected into code that knows to accept such functions.

The "host" code than only needs to `call` or `apply` them, knowing that `this` will refer to itself - this very "host" object.

This leads to a more concise, reusable and portable code, IMO.

UPDATE 2:

See more [here](https://medium.com/the-javascript-collection/9e6122cde639).

Comment: maybe my choise to call the first parameter `that` was not a great one :) but the point is that its a function that works on some object. but does not belong to it. and that is why it seemed odd to me to begin with that the author of that function chose to use `this` inside it and then `.call` it instead of just passing the object as a parameter.

Comment: "JavaScript does neeed this" ? or "Doesn't" ?
I understand that it can be done this way (i.e. "standalone" functions that refer to this in their code and objects that use those functions as if they where there own via call. I respect your opinion, But I don't find this code pattern to be any more concise, reusable or  portable.  Moreover, seeing the performance difference and the fact I think I will go with the direct call pattern...

Comment: If you don't see how it's more concise or reusable, I can't help you. I find your way of coding extremely ugly and I think that there is simply no way you'd notice the difference between the calls in real world and in normal use cases. Additionally, I leave to browser vendors to take care of performance issues and worry about writing good code. Optimizing to get some function call from 10 ns to 1 ns is not worth the ugliness (and that is without going into a lengthy discussion on validity of said performance results).

Comment: also I looked at the link in your update 2 and it is funny that the `_.first` method they use to demonstrate the use of `.call` is actually designed to be called and no `.call()`ed if indeed using .call was so great then why not design for a usage pattern of `_.first.call([1,3,4],2)` (your way) instead of `_.first([1,3,4],2)`  (my way) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern will work in this scenario but in general it has some problems ...

1. Constructor functions -> We create objects by using new keyword where 'this' object is automatically created and returned (default) also has the link with the function's prototype.
2. When calling the function someone might forget to pass 'that' object and your code will fail. In case of call if you pass null it is reset to global object (non-strict mode which is common)

Comment: constructors must use this... its appropriate and within context and there is no other way... as for forgetting to pass 'that' well - you can forget many other things... but `doSomthingTo(thisObject,likeThat) ` is shorter and more readable (IMHO) then `doSomething.call(usingThisContext,likeThat)` not to mention that you might end up forgetting .call and trying to use `doSomething(usingThisContext,likeThat)` or (if you think that someone might forget to pass 'that` `doSomething.call(likeThat)`